# Do adhoc builds get replaced by app store updates?

Tags: ios, app-store, ad-hoc-distribution

Assuming I have:

1. Installed the current **app store** build bundleID `com.a.b`
2. Then installed an ad **hoc build** with the same bundleID `com.a.b` (i.e. replaced the build from step 1)
3. Then and update to the app store is released.

---

- Will the new update automatically install over the top of my installed ad hoc?
- Or will I have to manually delete and re-install the app store build again?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The bundle id is unique across the device. If you install and ad hoc build with an id of `com.a.b` and then download an app from the app store with `com.a.b` then it will write over the ad hoc build.

This is why it is enforced as unique when creating the app on iTunes Connect.

And yes, it will automatically install over the top.